# Strategies for Bob Jenkins

Tags: arkham-horror

I'm playing Arkham Horror for the first time and I randomly drew Bob Jenkins as my investigator. With some of the other players' characters, their "purpose" is pretty clear. There's the guy with high fight who starts with a sweet weapon, the guy with high lore and tons of spells, etc. With Bob, I'm not seeing a clear path to how I can best contribute. What type of strategies or tactics should I be employing to make the best use of my turn?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bob Jenkins is:

- Rich!  $9 -> Go shopping for Unique Items
- Has stuff: 2 common and 2 uniques, hopefully he starts with some good stuff
- Well rounded: 4 Sanity and 6 Stamina is a great split.  Enough Sanity to allow missing a horror check or two, and enough stamina to get down and dirty.
- Reasonably fast - speeds 4 and 5 are not out of the question.  Bob can get from place to place quickly.
- Has a strong will, minimum 3
- Can hopefully compensate for his somewhat poor fight skill with some good items

When playing Bob, you should be aggressive.  Bob has the stats and should have the items to allow him to survive most bad things.  If you get lucky and start with an **Elder Sign**, go off world as quick as you can.  If not, see if you can buy an Elder Sign, or start grabbing clue tokens.  Favor the locations where common items are found to take advantage of the **Shrewd Dealer** ability.  Bob may not be the best investigator at any particular thing, but odds are, he is the second best at most things in a normal group.  Use him to fill in for whatever your team is lacking.

According to the [Arkham Horror Statistics Report](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AliZyklaTCWzcGFQTWdvZW5jc1JwcHEzUEVZV1htUVE&hl=en_US), Bob has the 7th highest winning percentage (out of 48 characters) in October 2010.  For November, he has moved to 6th.

Comment: I think I got a bad initial draw for the random items. Everything is a tome that requires a Lore (-1) check. I'll just have to head over and get more unique items.

Comment: @Jonathan - Tomes aren't that great for Bob.  You can always meet up with a fellow investigator with a higher lore and give them the tomes.  If they can give you a nice weapon at the same time, then everyone gets better.